# How to obtain the field names and types of an model?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am developing a library to generate tables and forms automatically.

The user passes the GORM connection and a list of models.

I would like to know how to obtain field names, types, and other info from a specific model.

Comment: What have you tried? (looking at how [GORM does this](https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/blob/master/schema/schema.go#L80) should provide a good starting point).

Answer (score 1):

Use the reflect package

```
func FieldNames(models []interface{})  {
    for _, itf := range models {
        model := reflect.TypeOf(itf)
        if model.Kind() == reflect.Struct{
            fieldCnt := model.NumField()
            startIdx := 0
            for startIdx < fieldCnt {
                model.Field(startIdx).Name //this gives you the name of fields in each model
                startIdx+=1
            }
        }
    }
}
```